# Own NameServer with mail and FTP

Tags: apache-2.4, bind, vps, domains

I don't even know where to start, i have a vps, two domains, i pointed one domain via direct IP in my domain provider, followed a guide to install bind9 (what i thought i needed) and generated ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com, then my second domainn pointed to ns1 and ns2, but im stucked there, everybody suggest name based vhosts, but the problem is how do i configure there the email and ftp record (mail.domain2.com) i can't find the answer, please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not so hard to find the answer to your questions if you google for about 15 seconds. Anyways, here are the records you need:

Mail server:

```
example.com. MX 10 mail.example.com.
```

FTP server (?):

```
ftp A 1.2.3.4
```

Before anything more, I'll save you those 15 seconds, [read](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/dns/dns-records-an-introduction)